# Pacman collision detection using a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, pacman

I have a 2 dimensional array called `board`, that is 32x32. Every element is `0` for clear path or `-1` for wall.

The window resolution is 800x800, meaning every element of `board` has width and height of 25.

My pacman position is in screen coordinates. I'm trying to implement the next two functions to basically know if I can move Pacman to some position (in screen coordinates).

```
public static boolean canMove(Pair<Integer> pacmanPos, int[][] board) {
    Pair<Integer> boardPos = pacmanPosToBoardPos(pacmanPos);

    int j = boardPos.getX();
    int i = boardPos.getY();

    return board[i][j] != -1;
}

public static Pair<Integer> pacmanPosToBoardPos(Pair<Integer> pacmanPos) {
    int x = pacmanPos.getX();
    int y = pacmanPos.getY();

    int newX = (int)Math.round((double)(x+12.5) / 25.0) % 32;
    int newY = (int)Math.round((double)(y+12.5) / 25.0) % 32;

    return new Pair<Integer>(newX, newY);
}
```

This was my best shot. I added 12.5 to x and y to refer to the "center" of the some element of `board`, if that makes sense.

Obviously this does not work and Pacman runs into walls :( . Any idea?

Comment: Don't work in screen coordinates.  Separate the virtual position on the board (32x32) from the representation on the screen. Perform all calculation in virtual board positions and convert to screen coordinates ONLY at the last possible moment, to render the actual display.  It will be MUCH simpler that way.

Comment: No, no idea but your approach seems ok. You just need to debug what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @JimGarrison But I want to move Pacman smoothly, so I have to use screen coordinates

Comment: @Pilpel, no, you don't have to work in screen coordinates.  You decide whether or not you want to move to a new position in grid coordinates on the board.  Once you've made that decision, the rest of the move is rendering.  If you want to reverse direction, you can do so during the rendering process, but you already have the decision: both the old and new positions are valid.  If you're working with partial-position collisions as other sprites move into the old position, then you're not really working with discrete board elements.  However, I say that walls are impossible; sprites encounters.

Comment: Separating the _model_ (board coordinates) from the _view_ (screen coordinates) is a basic, fundamental concept in any programming to do with visual display.  As @Prune says, at every time step you have a starting position and an ending position, and what happens on the screen between those two is merely painting and animation.  If you need to interrupt that process in the middle and change it, that just becomes a new ending position.  You update the model and the rendering code makes it happen on screen.  The sooner you adopt this idea the easier the coding will be.

Comment: But I still need to convert screen position to board position, no?

Comment: @Pilpel In general, no: your *model* is the official ground-truth representation of the game state.  Your world of screen coordinates is merely for the convenience of optical-based life forms.  The flow is entirely from the official (board coordinates) to the visual (screen coordinates).  If the two are ever out of sync, the model is correct and the view needs updating.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the following mapping:

```
co-ordinates     board pos

0-24             0
25-49            1
50-74            2
etc
```

then just use integer division

```
int newX = (x / 25) % 32;
int newY = (y / 25) % 32;
```

If you want to actually perform collision, and your Pacman has a width and height, you need to offset the co-ordinates from the center of the Pacman when you test. For example, if you are moving right and your Pacman is 25 pixels wide, then add 12.5 to the x co-ordinate that you want to test (and subtract if you are moving left etc). To avoid using non-integers, you can put your "centerpoint" in the top left of the Pacman, and add 25 when moving right or down, and 0 with moving left or up.

If you want to separate the rendering from the model, do the above calculations in "game units" or whatever unit you store the Pacman's position in rather than pixels, and then apply a transformation to screen co-ordinates when you render. However, you do need to have some mapping between grid indices and these game units (even if that just means storing positions as grid indices with a fractional part and throwing it away when you want the index), because collisions (e.g. with ghosts) do not necessarily occur at grid cell boundaries. Of course, if you want "pixel perfect" collision, then the mapping between the units you do collision in and the rendering units can be 1:1.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. I think I want `26-50` to map to `2`, `51-75` to `3` and so on. Can't figure out the required calculation though